# How to use Spark hadoopFile method to use custom input format with value type Text?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

How to use Spark hadoopFile method to use custom input format with value type Text?  For example `OmnitureDataFileInputFormat` for processing Omniture Click Stream data?

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.rassee.omniture.hadoop.mapred.OmnitureDataFileInputFormat
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import org.apache.hadoop.io.{LongWritable, Text}
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputFormat

val rddLines: RDD[String] =
  sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopFile(
    path = path,
    inputFormatClass = classOf[OmnitureDataFileInputFormat],
    keyClass = classOf[LongWritable],
    valueClass = classOf[Text]
  )
  .map(_._2.copyBytes()).map(new String(_, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```